# CSR approval from jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, openshift, jenkins-groovy, csr

I have a pipeline to get the csr and approve.

I am able to get the pending csrs and approve them with the below command.

```
sh "oc get csr "
sh "xargs oc adm certificate approve"
```

Now coming to the actual issue. When there are CSRs pending the above method works fine. When there are no resources found the pipeline ends in Failure which should not happen. I still want the pipeline to succeed with a message stating all nodes are up to date and no csrs are pending for approval.

PFB the error:

```
 + oc get csr
 No resources found.    
 + xargs oc adm certificate approve
 error: one or more CSRs must be specified as <name> or -f <filename>

ERROR: script returned exit code 123
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two separate commands there is nothing to prevent the second one from running which causes the error.
You shouldn’t be running the approval step unless there are any pending certificates.

I found a solution [here](https://codepre.com/how-to-list-and-approve-pending-csrs-in-openshift-4-x.html) which should work for you:

```
sh "for i in `oc get csr --no-headers | grep -i pending |  awk '{ print $1 }'`; do oc adm certificate approve $i; done"
```